# Google Maps API 3: Unwanted polygon line on touch devices

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, touch

I've stumbled upon this issue when drawing a polygon on a touch screen device:

- Drawing mode is set to google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
- User pans the map by touch, hold and then dragging the finger on the screen.
- Then the user taps on the screen to start the creation of a polygon. BUT then a "ghost" line is drawn from where the map was centered before to the position of the starting point of the polygon. Screenshot from my iPhone:

[image: Map]

The line looks like what you get when the mouse pointer is hovering over the map on a desktop browser. But of course a touch device does not have a mouse pointer. Maybe it's a mouse-event bug in the GMaps API?

**Any suggestions on how to avoid/remove this unwanted line?**

It's possible to reproduce the issue with by pointing your smart phone/pad to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w1my558L/.

```
$(function () {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(60.629765, 6.424094);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingControl: false,
    polygonOptions: {
        editable: true
    }
});    

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);    
drawingManager.setMap(map);       
drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer an issue with the latest version of Google Maps API. I upgraded to version 3.10 and the problem went away.